# getting multiple outputs from matlab to c#

Tags: matlab, c#-4.0, .net-assembly

I have written some functions in matlab.Now I need to get their outputs to C# .net form.I could success fully connect them through .Net Assembly and able to get output of a function which returns only one output to c#.Now I want to do it with a function which returns multiple outputs.Is there any particular way of doing this?????

thanks...

Answer (score 4):

there are different signrature of the method available in the DLL, just use the proper one, 
put the first input argument of the method as the number of outputs, then it will return an array of MWArray as outputs : (i.e below, 2 indicates that I expect to have an array of outputs with size 2)

```
    MWArray[] res = MatlabDll.callMethod(2, x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

C# uses the [Tuple Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) for solving this issue.